# How is an int function able to return long long variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, int, long-integer

```
int reverse(int x) {
        if(x==0)
            return 0;
        int y = abs(x);
        long long result = 0;
        while(y > 0) {
            result *= 10;
            result += y % 10;
            y /= 10;
        }
        if(result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN)
            return 0;
        if(x<0) {
            return -result;
        }
        return result;
        
    }
```

How is this code valid? It's clear that result is a long long variable but the return type of the code is int. The code still works.

Comment: Turn on (increase) the compiler's warning level.

Comment: Did you check for warnings? Compiler might be telling you about precision loss.

Comment: If `result` equals `INT_MIN` is will be out of range when `-result` is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value will silently be truncated if the value exceeds the range of `int`.

Your compiler likely has warnings you can enable that tells you this. You should enable them (and also ask it to turn warnings into errors IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

There are [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) between all numeric types. The `return` of a function is one place these can occur.

For `long long` -> `int`

> If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type. Otherwise the result is implementation-defined. (Note that this is different from signed integer arithmetic overflow, which is undefined).

In the function you show, the result is representable as an `int`, except on common systems `-INT_MIN` is larger than `INT_MAX`.